# Android Admob: missing google_app_id

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to implement a rewarded ad using google dev guides [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) and [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video) , the ad shows up and the callbacks are called normally when using the test ad-unit `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917` on the emulator , then I replaced the test ad unit with mine, launched on a physical device, the ad doesn't load up and function `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad` is called.

in the log I found

> GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from string resources with name google_app_id.

I went on and created a firebase account just to download `google-services.json` and get the `mobilesdk_app_id`, then I added it to the Strings resources. Now when it launches the ad fails to load again, and I found this in the log

> Disabling data collection. Found google_app_id in strings.xml but Google Analytics for Firebase is missing. Remove this value or add Google Analytics for Firebase to resume data collection.

I'm using `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0`
I couldn't find anything in the guide to help

Answer (score 0):

Did you add add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to the bottom of your modules build.gradle?

You app_id needs to go to your AndroidManifest.xml as well

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

see here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml